# Problems to hide div using window.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function, var

I´m trying to hide a div inside other div when I click outside of parent. The problem is that I don't want to use ID because I would like that this was a global function (sorry for my English).

Now I select the child using in the parent element `onclick="myfunction(this)"` and then (in the script), doing a variable with `element.children[0]` to show the child.

The problem is when I try to hide the child clicking outside of parent because the variables depend on `myfunction`.

```js
    function myfunction(elmnt) {
        var child = elmnt.children[0];
        if (child.style.display === "none") {
            child.style.display = "block";} 
        else {
            child.style.display = "none";};



//        window.onclick = function(event) {child.style.display = "none";}

    }
```

```html
    <div class="parent" style="margin:10px; cursor:pointer; background-color:lime; width:150px; height:50px;" onclick="myfunction(this)">
        <div class="child" style="100px; height:20px; color: black; background-color:red; display:none;">Child1</div>
    </div>
    
        <div class="parent" style="margin:10px; cursor:pointer; background-color:lime; width:150px; height:50px;" onclick="myfunction(this)">
        <div class="child" style="100px; height:20px; color: black; background-color:red; display:none;">Child2</div>
    </div>
    
    
        <div class="parent" style="margin:10px; cursor:pointer; background-color:lime; width:150px; height:50px;" onclick="myfunction(this)">
        <div class="child" style="100px; height:20px; color: black; background-color:red; display:none;">Child3</div>
    </div>
```

Now the function that toggles display:block/none the child works, but the function that should hide the child when clicking outside the parent does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Manul gave the correct answer, but set event on window is not correct.

Need to handle the need to execute a handler. To avoid errors and unnecessary load in the interface.

```js
var globalEventSet = false;

function myfunction(elmnt, e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  var child = elmnt.children[0];
  
  if (child.style.display === "none") {
    if(!globalEventSet){
      setEventOnWindow()
      globalEventSet = true;
    }
    
    child.style.display = "block";
  } 
  else {
    child.style.display = "none";
  }

}

function setEventOnWindow(){

  let callback = function(ev) {
    var childList = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
    
    if(childList != null) {
       [...childList].forEach(function(child){
            child.style.display = "none";
       })
    } 
    
    console.log("i'm work only once (;");
    
    window.removeEventListener('click', callback );
    
    globalEventSet = false;
  }

  window.addEventListener('click', callback );
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" style="margin:10px; cursor:pointer; background-color:lime; width:150px; height:50px;" onclick="myfunction(this, event)">
    <div class="child" style="100px; height:20px; color: black; background-color:red; display:none;">Child1</div>
</div>

<div class="parent" style="margin:10px; cursor:pointer; background-color:lime; width:150px; height:50px;" onclick="myfunction(this, event)">
    <div class="child" style="100px; height:20px; color: black; background-color:red; display:none;">Child2</div>
</div>


<div class="parent" style="margin:10px; cursor:pointer; background-color:lime; width:150px; height:50px;" onclick="myfunction(this, event)">
    <div class="child" style="100px; height:20px; color: black; background-color:red; display:none;">Child3</div>
</div>
```